# Micronucleus firmware 2.6.1 - Activate bootloader put D- pin to high

Tags: wires

I flashed my ATTINY85 Digispark v3.0 with micronucleus firmware 2.6.1 and it works fine, the onboard led lights up and the another led blinks twines every 500ms (not sure way but it seams like everything is working correcly). But now I don't understand how to activate the "flash" mode to upload my program or upload a new bootloader.

I'm familiar with pull-up resistor but have never used it on a USB pins before (If I'm not mistaking the bootloader is activated to receiver programing when USB Data minus have a pull-up resistor and the board is reset and not only powered on).

Below are the condition to enter bootloader, text copied from micronucleus github page. https://github.com/ArminJo/micronucleus-firmware#entry_d_minus_pullup_activated_and_entry_ext_reset-entry-condition

**ENTRY_D_MINUS_PULLUP_ACTIVATED_AND_ENTRY_EXT_RESET**

*Activate the bootloader only if the D- pin is high, i.e. a pull-up resistor is attached and powered and we have an ENTRY_EXT_RESET condition. Useful if the pull-up is powered by USB V+ and NOT ATtiny VCC to save power. In this case often a schottky diode is connected between V and VCC.*

I have tried using a resistor from USB V+ to USB D- and resetting it using PIN 5 to ground but the leds just blinks to indicate a reset but no connection to is establish.

So if someone knows how this should work let me know.

[image: USB pin's - ATTINY85 Digispark v3.0]